# Need Snowflake timestamp in MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the date in mm/dd/yyyy fromat

```
select to_timestamp('03/30/2018','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

This gave me output : 2018-03-30 00:00:00.000000 .
But my expected output is 03/30/2018 .

I just want my string to be converted to date or timestamp format

could someone please help me with workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You are converting your string to timestamp, and this is why you get this result. You can use to_date to convert it to a date:

```
select to_date('03/30/2018','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

The default format of the date is YYYY-MM-DD. You can change DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT if you would like to see the dates as DD/MM/YYYY:

```
alter session set DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYYY';
select to_date('03/30/2018','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#date-output-format